# Get distinct row by primary key, but use value from another column

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to get the sum of the total time that was spent sending all emails within a campaign.

Because of the joins in my query I end up with the 'processing_time' column duplicated over many rows. So running `sum(s.processing_time) as send_time` will always over represent how long it took to run.

```
select
  c.id,
  c.sender,
  c.subject,
  count(*) as total_items,
  count(distinct s.id) as sends,
  sum(s.processing_time) as send_time,

from campaigns c
left join sends s on c.id = s.campaigns_id
left join opens o on s.id = o.sends_id

group by c.id;
```

I'd ideally like to do something like `sum(s.processing_time when distinct s.id)` but I can't quite work out how to achieve that.

I have made other attempts using `case` but I always run into the same issue, I need to get the distinct rows based on the ID column, but work with another column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want statistics related to distinct `s.id` as well as `c.id`, group by both columns. Collect the (intermediate) data that you need,
and use this table as the inner table in a nested sub-select query.
In the outer select, group by `c.id` alone.

Since the inner select groups by `s.id`, values which are unique per `s.id` will not get double-counted when you sum/group by `c.id`.

```
SELECT id
    , sender
    , subject
    , sum(total_items) as total_items
    , sum(sends) as sends
    , sum(processing_time) as send_time
FROM (
    SELECT
        c.id
        , s.id as sid
        , count(*) as total_items
        , 1 as sends
        , s.processing_time
        , c.sender
        , c.subject
    FROM campaigns c
    LEFT JOIN sends s on c.id = s.campaigns_id
    LEFT JOIN opens o on s.id = o.sends_id
    GROUP BY c.id, c.sender, c.subject, s.processing_time, s.id) t
GROUP BY id, sender, subject
ORDER BY id
```

Since the final table includes `sender` and `subject`, you'll need to group by these columns as well to avoid an error such as:

```
ERROR:  column "c.sender" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 14:         , c.sender
```